# How to reiterate a postman test for number of array elements?

Tags: for-loop, postman

I would like to validate an element using Postman which appears n number of times in a response. For example, an API which results into an array ('catalog_list_items') of elements:

```
{
  "data": {
    "catalog_list_items": [
      {
        "title": "epi444",
        "content_id": "58d379a601778507910005ed",
        "sequence_no": 1,
        "language": "kannada"
        } 
] 
      "catalog_list_items": [
      {
        "title": "epi434",
        "content_id": "58d37sds9a601778507910005ed",
        "sequence_no": 2,
        "language": "kannada"
        }
]
       "catalog_list_items": [
      {
        "title": "epi444",
        "content_id": "58d379a601778507910005ed",
        "sequence_no": 1,
        "language": "kannada"
        } 
]
}
}
```

Now, I want to validate that 'sequence_no' is always an integer but I don't know the number of times it appears in the response. Any help in this (using for loop or any external library) is really appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can try a script in the test part of postman. The script will be something similar to.

```
     var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

    for(i=0; i<jsonData.data.length; i++){
        test["Loop Tests"] = jsonData[i].catalog_list_items.sequence_no >= 0;
    }
```